# How to beatmatch a section of a track using free software (on Windows) to create a ringtone?

Tags: audio, windows, freeware

To my amusement I haven't found any readily made ringtone of the song Cellular Phone by Dopplereffekt. I just want to make the main theme (about 3.5 sec.) to a cool ringtone but I don't know how to match the beat. So after the theme ends, it should start again by matching the beat.

How do I accomplish this by using free software on Windows? I have Audacity. I can also download free trial version of paid software as well.

Ps. You can find the song on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8lLTYmpE8I). I think that's fair use to cut that 3.5 secs out of it. I know how to extract the audio out of YouTube (using FlashGot with Firefox, then extract the audio with FLV Extract), convert it to a WAV (with Fre:ac) and import it to editor software, I just fall short of the beatmatch part.

So far I learned from @Ken that this "beatmatching" is called *editing by signature and bars*.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what are you after exactly. Do you just want to cut out these 3 seconds and make a repetitive ringtone out of it?

Comment: It's not beat-match per-se you need, but editing by signature and bars. The track has 4/4 signature. Count 64 bars (4 beat per bar) to find loopable points as this track is produced by modern dance track patterns (16+16 bars x 2).

Comment: @Eugene S: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware Which bars are you talking about? He's asking about cutting audio file, not pattern.

Comment: @EugeneS If he's gonna make a loop from the music (he provided example) he need to cut by bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need, is just manually find the repeatable part of the song you want to use, create new track in Audacity and multiply this part desired amount of times. Simply speaking, just cut it when it feels right and then copy paste the same part one after another. If it doesn't sound plausible, re-cut.

Most "beat-finders" just find the BPM value and will not help you here.

Comment: Actually I need just one segment, then repeat it. Shift+Space with Audacity. Your suggested solution is not easy to implement.

Comment: @listen Yes, this is exactly what I was suggesting. It might be not the easiest however the only one possible as long as you deal with audio file (and not MIDI pattern). Good luck